# Adding a max date subquery to a group by clause

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, crystal-reports, subquery, correlated-subquery

I need to add a max transactional date to this report, so I can see the most recent transaction date for a patient who does not fall under the parameters in the query. This report will be going into a crystal report and I plan to put the last date of service date in the group header for each patient. The code below is to get the max date for each patient. I need the results inserted, so it takes the patients who fall under the below report and gives their max date. Regardless of what is entered for a date. Thank you in advance. SQL Server 2005.

```
select 
patient_id, 
Max(proc_chron) 

from patient_clin_tran pct
group by patient_id
```

The Code for the transaction

```
select patient_id,

(select p.case_status from patient p where p.patient_id = btb.patient_id and p.episode_id = (select max(episode_id) from patient p2 where p2.patient_id = p.patient_id)) as 'Status',
(select p.lname +', '+ p.fname from patient p where p.patient_id = btb.patient_id and p.episode_id = (select max(episode_id) from patient p2 where p2.patient_id = p.patient_id)) AS 'client',
Coverage_plan_id, 
(select proc_code from billing_transaction bt where bt.clinical_transaction_no = btb.clinical_transaction_no and bt.coverage_plan_id=btb.coverage_plan_id and bt.coverage_plan_id = btb.coverage_plan_id) as 'Procedure',
proc_chron, 
(select billing_amt from billing_transaction bt where bt.clinical_transaction_no = btb.clinical_transaction_no and bt.coverage_plan_id = btb.coverage_plan_id) as 'Billing Amount',
balance_amount,
(select max (accounting_date) from  billing_ledger bl where bl.clinical_transaction_no = btb.clinical_transaction_no and subtype = 'pa' and bl.coverage_plan_id = 'standard') as 'Last Payment on Trans',
(select max (instrument_date) from payment p where p.patient_id = btb.patient_id and  p.coverage_plan_id = 'standard') as 'Last Payment on Acct',
(select sum(balance_amount) from billing_transaction_balance btb2 where btb2.patient_id=btb.patient_id and btb2.coverage_plan_id=btb.coverage_plan_id and proc_chron <= CONVERT(CHAR(6), DATEADD(year, -1, DATEDIFF(day, 0,GETDATE())), 112) + '01' and btb2.coverage_plan_id   in('standard')) AS 'Balance'

from billing_transaction_balance btb

where proc_chron <= CONVERT(CHAR(6), DATEADD(year, -1, DATEDIFF(day, 0, GETDATE())), 112) + '01' and coverage_plan_id   in('standard') 

group by patient_id, proc_chron, coverage_plan_id, balance_amount, clinical_transaction_no
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your transaction code, you need to add all the Select columns which are not being aggregated to the Group By. I count 8 non-aggregated columns in the Select statement, so you must have all 8 in the Group By.

Comment: The things in the group by don't really match the group by I noticed as well. What would the sub query code for adding in the max date(proc_chron) for each patient be?

Comment: If you just want to get the max(proc_chron) from billing_transaction_balance btb in the transaction code above, all you have to do is change proc_chron to max(proc_chron) in the select and remove it from the group by.

Comment: (select Max(btb.proc_chron)), Something like that? Because it doesn't give me the most recent transaction.

Comment: OK that may be because all of the other columns you are grouping by. Can you simplify this query by removing any extraneous columns? If not add a where clause that limits the valid proc_chron for each patient_id by joining to the same table. Something like:

Comment: and btb.proc_chron = (select max(btb3.proc_chron) 
from billing_transaction_balance btb3 
where btb3.patient_id=btb.patient_id
and proc_chron <= CONVERT(CHAR(6), DATEADD(year, -1, DATEDIFF(day, 0,GETDATE())), 112) + '01')

Comment: I may have forgotten a btb3. in there, but can you see what I am going for?

Comment: I do. The reason it's grouped weird is, because of how it is in the crystal report that it will eventually go in. I'm home for the weekend, but I'll play with this first thing on Monday and see if I can get the code to do what I want with what you gave me. Thank you very much for your help. It's kinda weird, because what they want in the crystal report is for the group header which is a patient to have a most recent transaction excluding the parameters of the transaction it's showing. A weird request for a transactional report.

Comment: Had to tweak it a bit, but it got me close enough to be able to do it on my own. Thank you for your help.